# Centering scroll navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the navigation bar that appears when you scroll down on http://digitalblare.com. I've managed to center it when it's part of the fullscreen horizontal bar that appears on the website before you scroll down, but this is just totally beyond me. Thanks in advance for any help!

this is the CSS used to center the menu before you scroll:

```
.top-menu { width: 1045px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Really basic stuff. Once scrolled down though I can't for the life of me figure out what to code or other which # or . to put it.

Comment: Can you show some relevant code please?

Comment: Of course, sorry - so this is the CSS used to center the menu before you scroll:

.top-menu {
width: 1045px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

Really basic stuff. Once scrolled down though I can't for the life of me figure out what to code or other which # or . to put it.

Comment: are you trying to center that when its scrolling??

Comment: Exactly, center it when its scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the width in following css

```
.top_menu { /* #main-nav.fixed-nav */
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It worked for me, tried on link provided. 
if you want to keep that minimum width then update to

```
.top_menu { /* #main-nav.fixed-nav */
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1045px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and sorry, not sure which code to share. Here's a link to an image showing the problem: http://digitalblare.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Untitled-1.png

I tried inputting the code you provided but the problem's persisting.

Comment: In the image the property added is showing error, i think you missed the semicolon between width: 100% and margin: 0 auto, it should be width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

It changes to fixed position by js.. So add this to your CSS

```
#main-nav.fixed-nav{
left:50%;
margin-left: -522px; /* half of 1045 px */
}
```